# Book about time travellers finding world with robot vs human gladiators and 100 ft jesus robot

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Searching for SF book read in youth (80s)

1. Time travellers go to cryo-sleep in mountain crypt, perhaps to avoid fallout from nuclear war?
2. Wake up to find Earth much changed. Ruled by theocracies?
3. Heros participate in robot versus human gladiator battle
4. End up with two heros, controlling large humanoid robots used in religious parades, battle on the streets of a city
5. Recall one of the robots was a 100 foot jesus which had hundreds of bread loaves in its arm that shot out its hand a la miracle of loaves. Difficult image to forget, haha.

Any ideas?